# How to mock Schema::getColumnListing('t_schedule'); in phpunit in laravel

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I want to test my CSV import method in PHPUnit.
My PHPUnit test controller, I want to test CSV file imported and data insert into the database.
In TestDataCSV.php I have created required CSV files and arrays.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use \Mockery;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

include "TestDataCSV.php";

class scheduleCSVImportTest extends TestCase
{
    //use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;
    /**
     * Allocation unit test
     *
     * @dataProvider csvImportDataProvider
     */
    public function testconvert($scheduleCSVData, $scheduleTEXTData,$getColumnListingData,$expectedResultArr)
    {
        $mockMasterData = Mockery::mock('App\Http\Controllers\CsvController')->makePartial();        

        Schema::shouldReceive('getColumnListing')
                 ->with('t_schedule')
                 ->andReturn($getColumnListingData);       
                
        $actualResult = $mockMasterData->convert($scheduleCSVData,$scheduleTEXTData,'schedule');       
        
        $this->assertEquals($expectedResultArr, $actualResult);        
    }
    
    public function csvImportDataProvider()
    {
        return data();
    }
}
```

my csvController code is :

```
    public function convert($fp, $targetFile, $target_table)
    {
     ...........
     .........
     if ($target_table=='schedule') {
            $column_names = Schema::getColumnListing('t_schedule');
        }
    ...........
return [
            'message' => $message.
            "対象テーブル：[ $target_table_name ]<br>".
            "登録件数：[ $insert_count ]<br>".
            "更新件数：[ $update_count ]<br>",
            'target_table' => $target_table,
        ];
    }
```

when I print $column_names it shows an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock the static method using [Aliasing](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#aliasing):

> Alias mocks create a class alias with the given classname to stdClass
> and are generally used to enable the mocking of public static methods.
> . Expectations set on the new mock object which refer to static
> methods will be used by all static calls to this class.
>
> ```
> $mock = \Mockery::mock('alias:MyClass');
> ```